# How to connect to database using QOCI or QODBC with correct encoding?

Tags: python, database, oracle, pyqt, odbc

I want to connect to Oracle database using `PyQt5` `QOCI driver`. Here is some example code I'm using:

```
from PyQt5 import QtSql

# create connection
STAP = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC', 'STAP')
STAP.setDatabaseName("STAP")
STAP.setUserName("login")
STAP.setPassword("password")

# open connection
STAP.open()
```

but I get below error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QOCI driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
QSqlDatabase: an instance of QCoreApplication is required for loading driver plugins
```

Here's what I've tried:

1. Using `QODBC`, it connects but then I have a problem with special (`polish`) characters (like `ł`, `ń`), probably some encoding issues:

   ```
    MARCI�SKI LUKASZ
   ```
2. Adding path to driver to PATH: the message stoped showing, but still couldn't connect.
3. Checked the database parameters using this query (found [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/checking-oracle-database-encoding-779159222.html)):

   SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE PARAMETER='NLS_CHARACTERSET';

The result is:

```
PARAMETER=NLS_CHARACTERSET  
VALUE=EE8MSWIN1250
```

So I understand that database encoding is set to `Windows-1250`.

I tried converting the string to `bytearray` and then to `utf-8`:

```
result = 'MARCI�SKI LUKASZ'
result1 = bytearray(result, 'Windows-1250')
result2 = result1.decode('utf-8')
```

but I get error on converting the `polish characters` to `bytearray`:

```
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 5: character maps to <undefined>
```

I don't care which driver I'll use. I want to connect to database, and have database query items shown properly with special characters, but I **need** to create this connection using `PyQt5.QtSql` beacause I want to use this connection later for `PyQt` application I'm building.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a solution using

- Oracle Database 12c with Database Characterset AL32UTF8 (mandatory to store Unicode !!)
- SCOTT schema
- Oracle Instant client 12.2  with ODBC package (can be downloaded for free from Oracle)
- Oracle SQL Developer (Tool able to input Unicode characters and connect by Java/JDBC)
- Python 3.8

Python code below is in my understanding self explaining - only IP, PORT and SERVICE in connect string need to be changed. To watch the Unicode characters on shell/cmd, you need to set the environment variable

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

Unfortunatly this does not work on Eclipse IDE with PyDEV so I used try-except to get running code. Gave me a few hours headdache...

```
#  
# Safe python file as UTF-8 - otherwise you get no UTF-8 output !!!!
#
# Unix: 
#   export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
# 
# Windows:
#   set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
#
# Eclipse/PyDev: 
#   create for run/debug environment variable  
#   PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
#
# ODBC: 
#   Oracle Instantclient 12.2 + ODBC package
#
# DB:
#   Oracle RDBMS 12.2 with Database Characterset AL32UTF8 to allow Unicode
#
# SQL Tool to Execute SQL (JDBC)
#   Oracle SQL Developer
#
# SQL
#   connect scott/tiger
#   create table polish(col1 varchar2(50));
#   insert into polish(col1) values('SQLD ł ń');
#   commit;
#
# 
import pyodbc 

bl = " "
UTF8 = "UTF-8"     
strict = "Strict"
s1 = "Test "+UTF8
print(s1)
s1 = chr(322) + bl + chr(324) 
m = bytes(s1,UTF8)   
print(m)
try:       
    print(m.decode(UTF8,strict))
except:
    pass 
print()  

print("Test ODBC and " + UTF8)        
print("Test ODBC and " + UTF8)  
cs = "DRIVER={DRIVERNAME};UID={USERID};PWD={PASSWD};DBQ={IP_OR_HOSTNAME}:{PORT}/{SERVICE_OR_SID};"
csfill = cs.format(DRIVERNAME="Oracle in instantclient_12_2", 
                   IP_OR_HOSTNAME="111.222.33.44", 
                   PORT=12102, 
                   SERVICE_OR_SID="DB1212UTF",
                   USERID="SCOTT",
                   PASSWD="tiger")     
print(csfill)      
cn = pyodbc.connect(csfill)

cursor = cn.cursor()
# Do the insert - can be done using normal parameters and Unicode strings...
cursor.execute("insert into Polish(COL1) values ( ? )", u"Python ł ń")

# perform commit if want to inspect in SQL Developer
# cursor.commit()

cursor = cn.cursor()
# We need to cast COL1 so that unicode is shipped as ' \xxxx'
# unfortunatly Unicode deos not work directly 
# so we use ASCIISTR() to do that...
cursor.execute('SELECT ASCIISTR(COL1)"COL1" from Polish') 
rows = cursor.fetchall()


for row in rows: 
    s =""
    x = row.COL1   
    y = 0
    j = len(x)-1
    # Parse incoming column for Oracle-Style Unicode like ' \0142'
    while y <= j:
        if y + 5 <= j: 
            # detect if oracle unicode begins with blank and slash ->  ' \'
            sc = x[y]+x[y+1]
            if sc == " \\":
                # create unicode character
                c = x[y+2]+x[y+3]+x[y+4]+x[y+5]
                s += bl + chr(int(c,16))
                # step forward to next character
                y += 5  
            else:
                # no unicode 4 characters before end !! 
                s += chr(ord(x[y]))        
        else:
            # no unicode - regular ASCII
            s += chr(ord(x[y]))          
        y += 1  
    m = bytes(s,UTF8)     
    print(m)  
    try:
        print(m.decode(UTF8,strict))
    except:
        pass   
cursor.close()
cn.close()
```

Running application gives

```
Test UTF-8
b'\xc5\x82 \xc5\x84'
ł ń

Test ODBC and UTF-8
DRIVER=Oracle in instantclient_12_2;UID=SCOTT;PWD=tiger;DBQ=111.222.33.44:12102/DB1212UTF;
b'SQLD \xc5\x82 \xc5\x84'
SQLD ł ń
b'Python \xc5\x82 \xc5\x84'
Python ł ń
```

Comment: I see you're using `pyodbc`. I **need** to build this connection using `PyQt5.QtSql` because I later want to use this connection for PyQt application I'm building.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you download the Oracle SQL Developer which allows you to store polish characters corretly by performing

```
connect scott/tiger
create table polish(col1 varchar2(50));
insert into polish(col1) values('SQLD ł ń');
commit;
select COL1 from polish;
```

After that perform the row below using SQLPlus

```
set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250
sqlplus /nolog
```

and execute SQL:

```
connect scott/tiger
insert into polish(col1) values('SQL*PLUS ł ń');
commit;
```

and check if row is correctly represented in database doing

```
select * from Polish;
```

using SQL Developer - not SQL*Plus !!

This should return

```
SQLD ł ń
SQL*PLUS ł ń
```

If row inserted by SQL*Plus is different you got a problem and you may need to create a AL32UTF8 DB.

If SQL*Plus inserts correctly, try to implement the solution shown below

```
/* 
   WINDOWS:
   ========
   
   Oracle Instant Client 12.2 + ODBC Driver installed and registered in c:\oracle\instantclient_12_2
   
   create  following environment variables or use "set" before starting application from commandline
   
   ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle\instantclient_12_2
   PATH=%PATH%;%ORACLE_HOME%
   TNS_ADMIN=%ORACLE_HOME%
   NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250

   Replace in connect string below 
     111.222.33.44 by Server IP
     12102         by Port of TNS-Listener on Server 
     DB1212UTF     by Service or SID of Oracle DB
     
   create 

      %ORACLE_HOME%\sqlnet.ora

   i.e
   
     c:\oracle\instantclient_12_2\sqlnet.ora
     
   with lines
   
   DIAG_ADR_ENABLED = OFF
   TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = 16
   TRACE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT = c:\oracle\instantclient_12_2\trc
   
   create after that directory
   
   c:\oracle\instantclient_12_2\trc
   
   UNIX/LINUX:
   ===========

   Download Oracle Instant Client 12.2 + ODBC Driver into /tmp
   Oracle Instant Client 12.2 + ODBC Driver located in ~/oracle/instantclient_12_2
   i.e.
   
   $ mkdir ~/oracle
   $ cd ~/oracle
   $ unzip /tmp/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip
   $ unzip /tmp/instantclient-odbc-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0-2.zip
   $ unzip /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.2-odbc-12.2.0.1.0-2.zip
   $ unzip /tmp/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip 
   
   create  following environment variables or use "export" before starting application from commandline     
   
   export ORACLE_HOME=$HOME/oracl/instantclient_12_2
   export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME
   export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME
   export NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250

   Replace in connect string below 
     111.222.33.44 by Server IP
     12102         by Port of TNS-Listener on Server 
     DB1212UTF     by Service or SID of Oracle DB

   create directory
   
   mkdir -p ~/oracle/instantclient_12_2/trc
     
   create 

      $ORACLE_HOME/sqlnet.ora

   i.e
   
     ~/oracle/instantclient_12_2/sqlnet.ora
     
   with lines
   
   DIAG_ADR_ENABLED = OFF
   TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = 16
   TRACE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT = XXXX
   
   !!!! Replace the XXXX by the fully qualified path of !!!
   !!!! ~/oracle/instantclient_12_2/trc                 !!!
   
   perform
   
   cd $ORACLE_HOME
   ls libsqora*
   
   and write down name of ODBC driver - normally
   
   libsqora.so.12.1
   
   so maybe (*)
   
   /user/home/scotty/oracle/instantclient_12_2/libsqora.so.12.1
   
   Perform a SQL*Plus Connect to Database using no TNS entry and ensure Port,Host and service are correct:
   
   sqlplus scott/tiger@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=111.222.33.44)(PORT=12102))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DB1212UTF)))

   and perform a SELECT, after that exit
   
   in $ORACLE_HOME/trc should be a trace generated
   
   after that, build a simple QT application using the code below and 
   ensure Port,Host and service are corret.
   
   Normally, you could create a User DSN in ~.odbc.ini to use 
   
   DRIVER={Oracle in instantclient_12_2}
   
   or you qualify the library direct - like
   
   DRIVER={/user/home/scotty/oracle/instantclient_12_2/libsqora.so.12.1}
   
   start application and if not connecting, goto
   
   $ORCLE_HOME/trc
   
   and lookup for latest traces - they contain errors etc.
   
*/   

#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
       
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3");

 
    
    QString = "DRIVER={Oracle in instantclient_12_2};UID=SCOTT;PWD=tiger;DBQ=111.222.33.44:12102/DB1212UTF;"
   
    db.setDatabaseName(connectString);
    //db.setUserName("SCOTT"); // Set Login Username
    //db.setPassword("tiger"); // Set Password if required
    if(!db.open())
    {
        cout << "Can't Connect to DB !" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Connected Successfully to DB !";
        QSqlQuery query;
        query.prepare("SELECT COL1 FROM POLISH");
        if(!query.exec())
        {
            cout << "Can't Execute Query !" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Query Executed Successfully !";
            while(query.next())
            {
                cout << "COL1: " << query.value(0).toString() << endl;

            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please review my encoding from python - I use

```
SELECT ASCIISTR(COL1)"COL1" from Polish
```

which returns the unicode characters in Oracle style as regular ASCII codes - like

```
' \xxxx'
```

instead normal

```
'\uxxxx'
```

checkout how I evaluate/extract the unicodes from colums value  and build up a unicode string on my own.

Alternativly you my create a AL32UTF8 Database and use

```
NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8
```

Special characters often a mess when using non-Unicode characters.

Comment: I compared the INSERT's, and unfortunately I have two different strings:
SQLD ł ń
SQL*PLUS  ä
I can't create new database because I use clients database. What can I do?

Comment: First of all,  Windows console is a little bit tricky. Even if you Set NLS_LANG this does not mean Windows transfer correct stuff to SQLPlus. Good news is, that SQL Developer looks to insert and fetch characters correctly. Since SQL Developer uses true Unicode, theire is a valid NLS translation possible - even if this requires programmatic adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the issue with Client=Server on my RHEL server with

```
export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 
export NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8
```

which enables you even to enter all kind of Unicode characters in SQL*Plus -
retrieving and insert works perfect.

After that, switching to

```
export NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250
```

shows scrambled characters. Since we are still on terminal UTF-8 and Database is AL32UTF8 there must be a problems with EE8MSWIN1250 on Linux - but since AL32UTF8 works we do not have to care about

Switching to Windows Client finally gives correct results with

```
CHCP 1250
set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250
```

Search for "WORKING" below.

So - Next step is ODBC / QT. Will come back when QT has been build succesfully :-)

```
Server: Database 12.1.0.2 AL32UTF8 / RHEL 7.7 / LANG=de_DE.UTF-8

Client: W10Pro64bit / Instant client 12.1.0.2


SQL Developer:
==============
truncate table polish;
insert into polish(col1) values('SQLD ł ń');
commit;
select * from polish;

COL1
--------
SQLD ł ń

Server:
=======
export NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8

SQL> insert into polish(col1) values('XXXX ł ń');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from polish;

COL1
--------------------
SQLD ł ń
XXXX ł ń


export NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250

SQL>  insert into polish(col1) values('XXXX ł ń');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from polish;

COL1
--------------------
SQLD ▒ ▒
XXXX ▒ ▒
XXXX ł ń

SQL> commit;


SQL Developer:
==============
select * from polish;

COL1
--------
SQLD ł ń
XXXX ł ń
XXXX Ĺ‚ Ĺ„ 


CLIENT 
=======

C:\ORACLE\IC\12201\instantclient_12_2>set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8

C:\ORACLE\IC\12201\instantclient_12_2>chcp 65001
Aktive Codepage: 65001.

C:\ORACLE\IC\12201\instantclient_12_2>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wt Paź 13 01:44:50 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Data i godzina ostatniego pomyślnego logowania: Wt Paź 13 2020 01:38:45 +02:00

Połączono z:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Oracle Label Security, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select * from polish;

COL1
--------------------
SQLD ł ń
XXXX ł ń
XXXX Ĺ‚ Ĺ„

SQL>  insert into polish(col1) values('WIN ł ń');
  2  /
ERROR:
ORA-01740: w identyfikatorze brak jest znaku podwójnego cudzysłowu


WORKING
=======

C:\ORACLE\IC\12201\instantclient_12_2>set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250

C:\ORACLE\IC\12201\instantclient_12_2>chcp 1250
Aktive Codepage: 1250.

C:\ORACLE\IC\12201\instantclient_12_2>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wt Paź 13 02:20:52 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Data i godzina ostatniego pomyślnego logowania: Wt Paź 13 2020 02:17:14 +02:00

Połączono z:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Oracle Label Security, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select * from polish;

COL1
--------------------
SQLD ł ń
8859-2 ł ń
XXXX ł ń
XXXX Ĺ‚ Ĺ„

SQL> insert into polish(col1) values('WIN ł ń');

Utworzono wierszy: 1.

SQL> select * from polish;

COL1
--------------------
SQLD ł ń
WIN ł ń
8859-2 ł ń
XXXX ł ń
XXXX Ĺ‚ Ĺ„ 

SQL> commit;

Ukończono zatwierdzanie.

SQL> exit


SQL Developer
=============
SQLD ł ń
WIN ł ń
8859-2 ł ń
XXXX ł ń
XXXX Ĺ‚ Ĺ„
```

Answer (score 1):

OK - setting on command line

```
set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8
chcp 65001
```

and executing the code

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtSql
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 200))    
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt messagebox example - pythonprogramminglanguage.com") 

        pybutton = QPushButton('Show messagebox', self)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
        pybutton.resize(200,64)
        pybutton.move(50, 50)        

    def clickMethod(self):
        from PyQt5 import QtSql
        from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMessageBox
        
        STAP = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC3')
        STAP.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Oracle in instantclient_12_2};UID=SCOTT;PWD=tiger;DBQ=nerva:12102/DB1212UTF;");
        STAP.open()
        
        Q = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        SQL = "SELECT COL1 FROM POLISH"
        Q.prepare(SQL)
        Q.exec_()
        rec = Q.record()
        
        rs = "Number of columns: {0}\n".format(rec.count())
        
        nameCol = rec.indexOf("COL1") # index of the field "name"
        while Q.next():
            rs += "{0}\n".format(Q.value(nameCol))
        
            
        QMessageBox.about(self, SQL , rs)
        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

gives

[image]

I think the issue is solved :-)

Comment: Executing the two lines before the using this code doesn't help:
set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8
chcp 65001
I still get � instead the polish characters.
I also had to modify your code because the query wasn't connected to open database connection, and I had to set userName and password as in my original question. Using connect string didn't work for me.

Comment: It makes no Sense to wrestle with code when DB charset wont work. Please create a table on EE8MSWIN1250 DB

Comment: Database `nls_language` is set as `POLISH`.

Comment: It makes no sence to wrestle with code when DB charset EE8MSWIN1250 is not able to store polish characters. 1. SQL Developer:
 create table polish (col1 varchar2(20));insert into polish(col1) values('WIN ł ń');commit;  2. cmd.exe: Set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8 chcp 65001 sqlplus  select * from polish;3. cmd.exe Set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250 chcp 1250 sqlplus  select * from polish;Please provide output of 2 und 3 from cmd.exe

Comment: I opened PowerShell in VS Code and wrote as you instructed.
Output2: WIN � �
Output3: WIN ł ń
I tried changing this setting before running the program, but I still get the � instead polish charcters. It's like changing this setting works just for SQLPLUS

Answer (score 0):

Ok - QT 5.15.1 compiled with MingW64 on W10 succesfully.

Building with QT Creator with g++ following code

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDriver>
#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

        QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3");

        QString connectString = QString("DRIVER={Oracle in instantclient_12_2};UID=SCOTT;PWD=tiger;DBQ=nerva:12102/DB1212UTF;");

        db.setDatabaseName(connectString);
        cout << "-----------------------" << endl
             << connectString.toStdString() << endl
             << "-----------------------" << endl;

        if(!db.open())
        {
            cout << "Can't Connect to DB !" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Connected Successfully to DB !" << endl;

            QSqlQuery query;

            QString SQL = QString("SELECT COL1 FROM POLISH");
            cout << "-----------------------" << endl
                 << SQL.toStdString() << endl
                 << "-----------------------" << endl;

            query.prepare(SQL);

            if(!query.exec())
            {
                cout << "Can't Execute Query !" << endl;
            }
            else
            {        
                cout << "Query Executed Successfully !" << endl
                     << "-----------------------" << endl;
                while(query.next())
                {
                    QString x = query.value(0).toString();

                     cout << "COL1: " <<  x.toStdString()  << endl;

                }
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Executing with different code pages and NLS_LANG settings

```
C:\DEV\QT\build-t1-Desktop-Debug\debug>chcp 1250
Aktive Codepage: 1250.

C:\DEV\QT\build-t1-Desktop-Debug\debug>set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250

C:\DEV\QT\build-t1-Desktop-Debug\debug>t1
-----------------------
DRIVER={Oracle in instantclient_12_2};UID=SCOTT;PWD=tiger;DBQ=nerva:12102/DB1212UTF;
-----------------------
Connected Successfully to DB !
-----------------------
SELECT COL1 FROM POLISH
-----------------------
Query Executed Successfully !
-----------------------
COL1: SQLD ďż˝ ďż˝
COL1: WIN ďż˝ ďż˝
COL1: 8859-2 ďż˝ ďż˝
COL1: XXXX ďż˝ ďż˝
COL1: XXXX Ĺ‚ Ĺ„

C:\DEV\QT\build-t1-Desktop-Debug\debug>chcp 65001
Aktive Codepage: 65001.

C:\DEV\QT\build-t1-Desktop-Debug\debug>set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250

C:\DEV\QT\build-t1-Desktop-Debug\debug>t1
-----------------------
DRIVER={Oracle in instantclient_12_2};UID=SCOTT;PWD=tiger;DBQ=nerva:12102/DB1212UTF;
-----------------------
Connected Successfully to DB !
-----------------------
SELECT COL1 FROM POLISH
-----------------------
Query Executed Successfully !
-----------------------
COL1: SQLD � �
COL1: WIN � �
COL1: 8859-2 � �
COL1: XXXX � �
COL1: XXXX ł ń

C:\DEV\QT\build-t1-Desktop-Debug\debug>chcp 1250
Aktive Codepage: 1250.

C:\DEV\QT\build-t1-Desktop-Debug\debug>set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8

C:\DEV\QT\build-t1-Desktop-Debug\debug>t1
-----------------------
DRIVER={Oracle in instantclient_12_2};UID=SCOTT;PWD=tiger;DBQ=nerva:12102/DB1212UTF;
-----------------------
Connected Successfully to DB !
-----------------------
SELECT COL1 FROM POLISH
-----------------------
Query Executed Successfully !
-----------------------
COL1: SQLD Ĺ‚ Ĺ„
COL1: WIN Ĺ‚ Ĺ„
COL1: 8859-2 Ĺ‚ Ĺ„
COL1: XXXX Ĺ‚ Ĺ„
COL1: XXXX Äąâ€š Äąâ€ž

C:\DEV\QT\build-t1-Desktop-Debug\debug>chcp 65001
Aktive Codepage: 65001.

C:\DEV\QT\build-t1-Desktop-Debug\debug>set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8

C:\DEV\QT\build-t1-Desktop-Debug\debug>t1
-----------------------
DRIVER={Oracle in instantclient_12_2};UID=SCOTT;PWD=tiger;DBQ=nerva:12102/DB1212UTF;
-----------------------
Connected Successfully to DB !
-----------------------
SELECT COL1 FROM POLISH
-----------------------
Query Executed Successfully !
-----------------------
COL1: SQLD ł ń
COL1: WIN ł ń
COL1: 8859-2 ł ń
COL1: XXXX ł ń
COL1: XXXX Ĺ‚ Ĺ„
```

So - comparing this with SQL*Plus tests, we got a strange behavior

SQL*Plus on Windows requires

```
set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250
chcp 1250
```

SQL*Plus on Unix requires

```
export NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8
export LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
```

QT/C++/ODBC application on Windows requires

```
set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8
chcp 65001
```

I assume that QT uses Unicode by default and so the behaviour is more comparable to Linux/Unix since POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8 is identical and codepage 65001 is equivalent to UTF-8.

Will test today or tomorrow PyQT5 ....

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. Can you provide me with step by step solution? I see you provided test results and not solution to my problem.

Comment: Please see my solution from Oct 13 6:24 (search for 6:24) It uses the PyQt5 and ODBC driver and is based on your initially code - only difference: I created a small GUI and when you press the button, DB gets connected by ODBC. Setup: create a simple table  "polish" with one column col1 of varchar2 on DB with AL32UTF8 charset, populate table with rows containing polish Characters using SQLDeveloper and commit, Open cmd.exe, set  set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8', execute
chcp 65001 to change to unicode codepage and execute on cmd.exe python script, press button, rows shown in messagebox

Comment: Strange when you insert rows with SQL*Plus using cmd.exe and Set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8 and execute chcp 65001 and insert row with SQLPLUS you got in  SQLDeveloper (only source of truth) scrambled characters. Using NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250 and chcp 1250 and insert by sqlplus work - select in  SQLDEVELOPER. In a second cmd.exe with NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8 and chcp 65001 start python an you see correct rows. So - the key fact is: When you are able to insert polish characters in your EE8MSWIN1250 DB w. SQLDeveloper and select brings back same values then pyQT5 work