# Python SQL*Plus subprocess Error: sgslunUDPNew: Unable to create communication endpoint

Tags: python, oracle, subprocess, sqlplus

So we are using python and sqlplus to export all tables to csv files. As we have some unicode data in our oracle database we need to set the `NLS_LANG` environment variable to `.AL32UTF8` in order for sqlplus to actually use utf-8 encoding when spooling to the `csv` files.

Doing this manually and setting the `NLS_LANG` variable in cmd works fine.

However the following python snippet:

```python
...

print("Connecting to database ...")
with subprocess.Popen(["C.\\My\\Path\\To\\sqlplus.exe", "MyUser/MyPassword@whocares.com:1522/MyDataBase"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8', env={"NLS_LANG": ".AL32UTF8"}) as p:
    p.stdin.write("set echo off newpage 0 pagesize 0 linesize 3000 feed off head off trimspool on \n")
    p.stdin.flush()

...
```

causes sqlplus to fail with this error:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Oct 16 15:24:37 2020
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

sgslunUDPNew: Unable to create communication endpoint
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Omitting the environment variable when opening the subprocess however works just fine:

```python
...


print("Connecting to database ...")
with subprocess.Popen(["C.\\My\\Path\\To\\sqlplus.exe", "MyUser/MyPassword@whocares.com:1522/MyDataBase"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8') as p:
    p.stdin.write("set echo off newpage 0 pagesize 0 linesize 3000 feed off head off trimspool on \n")
    p.stdin.flush()

...
```

Even more interesting is that it doesn't matter which environment variable we set. But as soon as we pass **any** environment variable to our sqlplus subprocess in python it crashes.

We are unsure if this is related to python or sqlplus or the combination of both and any help would be highly appreciated.

In terms of versions we are using `Windows 10` with `SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.8.0.0.0` and `Python 3.8.5`

Comment: This just looks hacky - and error prone as you discovered.  Hardcoding passwords is a big red flag in itself.  Why do you have to call SQL\*Plus from Python?  Both SQL\*Plus and Python have CSV support.   See https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/fast-generation-of-csv-and-json-from-oracle-database and https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html Personally I would export solely in Python using Oracle's cx_Oracle interface since Python has better flow control and file management.

Comment: First of all thank you for the links. I'll look into them on Monday. That the code above is awful and hacky is out of question and we'll surely find a different way around it :D However this stack overflow question was mainly because we were staggered that this awful python subprocess solution didn't work. And therefore we are looking mainly for a *why* instead of *how else*. Maybe someone has experienced something similar with python subprocessinng before and can give some insight in this weird bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - testing a little bit and get it working

```
import subprocess, os

line = "SCOTT/tiger@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyyy/sssss"    

# fails
# subprocess.run(["sqlplus.exe", line], env={"NLS_LANG": ".AL32UTF8"})

my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["NLS_LANG"] = ".AL32UTF8"

# works
# subprocess.run(["sqlplus.exe", line], env=my_env)

#adopting solution
print("Connecting to database ...")
with subprocess.Popen(["C:\\ORACLE\\IC\\12201\\instantclient_12_2\\sqlplus.exe", "SCOTT/tiger@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyyy/sssss"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8', env=my_env) as p:
    p.stdin.write("set echo off newpage 0 pagesize 0 linesize 3000 feed off head off trimspool on \n")
    p.stdin.flush()
```

OUTPUT

```
Connecting to database ...

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Oct 18 00:07:22 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Sun Oct 18 2020 00:04:57 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Oracle Label Security, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Oracle Label Security, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options
```

In the end it was no issue using NLS_LANG since even something like

```
subprocess.run(["sqlplus.exe", line], env={"A": "1"})
```

failed - you just need to create a valid environment like

```
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["NLS_LANG"] = ".AL32UTF8"
```

and assign it to the "env" in like

```
with subprocess.Popen( ..... , env=my_env)
```

Frank

Answer (score 1):

sgslunUDPNew: Unable to create communication endpoint
ERROR:
ORA-12154:
means that the Oracle network layer (TNS) tries to Open an invalid or prohibited port uses OS network libs - this could be result of a malformed or wrong encoded string containing the port - and at the end the TNS reports the error passing to SQL*Plus

So - since the SQLPLUS can be started, this gives oppertunity to test

with subprocess.Popen(["C.\My\Path\To\sqlplus.exe << EOF connect MyUser/MyPassword@whocares.com:1522/MyDataBase EOF ",["" ], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8', env={"NLS_LANG": ".AL32UTF8"}) as p:

Please see what "nice" results you face using Unicode - thats what I found a week ago. At the end I believe SQL*Plus may not able to decode unicode correct internally. Will test the stuff.

[How to connect to database using QOCI or QODBC with correct encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64281110/how-to-connect-to-database-using-qoci-or-qodbc-with-correct-encoding/64310959?noredirect=1#comment113730482_64310959)

Anyway - to get universal, consider using pyODBC with Oracle ODBC driver, which got official support  - or other ODBC for other DB